# How do I insert a dynamically generated table into a HTML table cell?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I previously posted this question but received no good answer. I have made the suggested modifications and am posting the less-abridged code.
I need to insert the dynamically generated table in the `resultsCell` in the larger table.

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td id="resultsCell" rowspan="2"></td>
            <td>
                <object id="map" class="mapClass"></object>
            </td>
       <tr>
            <td>
                <button id="download">Download Map</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I use the following JS code to dynamically generate the table:

```
var table = document.createElement("table");
table.setAttribute("class", "resultsTable");
table.setAttribute("id", "resultsTable");
//generating table logic
document.getElementById("resultsCell").appendChild(table);
```

The dynamically generated table is still outside the table I'm trying to insert it into.

Answer (score 0):

Don't see anything wrong with your code, have a look at my "modified" example. just assigned some styling to make the table visible.

```
var table = document.createElement("table");
table.setAttribute("class", "resultsTable");
table.setAttribute("id", "resultsTable");
table.style.width = '100px';
table.style.height = '100px';
table.style.border = '1px solid red';
//generating table logic
document.getElementById("resultsCell").appendChild(table);
```

[image]